# How do I test a Curl based FaceBook API implementation?

Tags: ruby, facebook, curl

I wrote my own FaceBook library that uses actual Curl requests, not libcurl.

Is there a way to test it? I'm asking this because most solutions involve using something like fakeweb which as far as I can tell will not work here.

The existing code can be found [on my github page](https://github.com/viseztrance/facebook_light).

Comment: Not to nitpick over moderator edits, but gosh, "FaceBook"?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could mock `Request.dispatcher` with an expected behavior, pretty much like Fakeweb would do.

There are a few examples on this file, specially https://github.com/chrisk/fakeweb/blob/master/lib/fake_web/ext/net_http.rb#L44.

Comment: I'm choosing this answer because you replied faster than the VCR library suggestion which would normally be my pick, but I did voted up everyone else as well as a token of my appreciation.

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to use a different host/port in test mode (eg localhost:12345)

Then in your test run a sinatra or webrick servlet on that port that you configure to respond to the requests your code should be making

Comment: With this approach you could easily use VCR in the proxy server to record & replay responses. See https://gist.github.com/1434673 and https://www.relishapp.com/myronmarston/vcr/docs/middleware/rack for examples.

Answer (score 1):

When running your tests/specs, monkey-patch the `run` method of your `Request` class to hook into the Marston [VCR library](https://github.com/myronmarston/vcr).  See the existing `library_hooks` subdir for examples and ideas on how to do this -- the [fakeweb](https://github.com/myronmarston/vcr/blob/master/lib/vcr/library_hooks/fakeweb.rb) implementation is a good place to start.

VCR works well with live services like Facebook's because it captures interactions "as is", and VCRs can be easily re-recorded when the services change.

I'm running into problems with your library, however.  You need to require the `cgi` and `json` libraries; it also looks like it requires a Rails environment (it's failing to find `with_indifferent_access` on `Hash`).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time of actually trying it. I was actually looking into VCR as well after watching a promising RailsCasts episode, however I was uncertain on how to proceed at the time.